# Java validating user integer input

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have written code which

1) Continously asking user to select number and check if input is integer

```
private static int readInputInt(String error) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (!s.hasNextInt()) {
        System.out.println(error);
        s.next();
    }
    int result = s.nextInt();
    //s.close(); 
    return result;
}
```

2) Continously asking user to select number within range and showing only errors, program do not show message to ask user to provide input once again.

```
private static int readInputInt(String error, int max) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    int result;
    do {
        while(!s.hasNextInt()) {
            //show error if it is not integer and get input once again
            System.out.println(error);
            s.next();
        }
        result = s.nextInt();
        // if result is integer check if it is bigger than max
        if(result > max) {
            System.out.println(error);
        }

    }while(result > max);
```

and I was wondering if there is any simpler way to do this because I spent too much time for this and I think it is rubbish way of coding.

Firsly I tought that below code will work:

```
private static int readInputInt(String error, int max) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (!s.hasNextInt() && (s.nextInt < max)) {
        System.out.println(error);
        s.next();
    }
    int result = s.nextInt();
    //s.close(); 
    return result;
}
```

but it don't work. For any help thank you!

Comment: First of all, you are using s.nextInt, which is a function so it should be s.nextInt(). Secondly, in that while loop you are invoking next() twice, that's incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private static int readInputInt(String error, int max) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    int result;
    while (true) { 
        if (s.hasNextInt()) {
            result = s.nextInt();    
            if (result <= max) {
                s.close();
                return result;
            }
         } else { //Only want to call next() if it doesn't meet the first conditional. We've already called next when it is an int. 
             s.next();
         }
         System.out.println(error);
    }
```

Comment: Holy s*** it works! Unfortunately I cannot place s.close(); because I have many methods which are using "Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);" and when I put in any "s.close();" then input is corrupted. Thank you!

Comment: If you're passing in scanner as an argument, that makes sense. But if you're creating a new scanner within each method, then something else is going on. Anyways, glad it worked out for you!

Answer (score 1):

I've come to this problem several times while writing code and the solution that usually works best for me is using

> try/catch

Let me show you what I mean.

```
private static int readInputInt(String error) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

        //1. Reading the input as a string.
        String input = s.nextLine();

        int result;

        // A while loop that will keep going on until the user enters a 
        // valid integer.
        while (true) {

           // Try/catch block that tries to parse the string to an integer
           try {

               // If the user enters a valid integer there will be no problem 
               // parsing it. Otherwise, the program will throw a 'NumberFormatException'.
               result = Integer.parseInt(input);


               // If the parsing has been successful, 
               //we break the while loop and return the result
               break;
           }catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {

               // If the user did not enter a valid integer we will just 
               // print the error message.
               System.out.println(error);
           }

           // Read user input again and repeat the procedure above.
           input = s.nextLine();
        }
        return result;
    }
```

I hope this helped. If you are not familiar with **try/catch** I suggest you read about it online. Its neat!

Comment: Very good and clear explanation "how any why" you have placed such code in particular place. Thank you!